# How to find out which NVIDIA GPU I have

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I'm trying to use the information in [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/performance_hardware.html) page to optimize my GPU performance. For that, I need to know which NVIDIA GPU I have.

I tried the command `sudo lshw -C display` and I'm getting the following output which is not very helpful:

```
*-display:0 UNCLAIMED   
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GD 5446
       vendor: Cirrus Logic
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e8000000-e9ffffff memory:ee080000-ee080fff
  *-display:1
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=64
       resources: irq:28 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:ea000000-ebffffff ioport:c100(size=128) memory:ee000000-ee07ffff
```

Can someone please point me as to how exactly to find out which NVIDIA GPU I have?

Thanks,
Gil

Answer (score 30, accepted):

please update your PCI ID database with:

```
sudo update-pciids
```

And use the following command in your terminal:

```
lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
```

You will see the model name of your graphic card. If it's ambiguous, you could search the PCI ID (something like [10de:11bc]) on the Internet for the corrent model name.

Comment: Not one single NVIDIA post said ANYTHING about this.  Probably because their support is 1 million times more incompetent than their actual coders.  #BridgeCoderDocumenterGaps

Answer (score 57):

If you have it installed, you can also use `nvidia-smi` which provides even more information for NVIDIA GPUs (this is, after all, what they use in the page you linked):

```
$ nvidia-smi

Mon Sep 15 16:02:31 2014       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.32     Driver Version: 340.32         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 650M     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   59C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      8MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you just want the GPU name:

```
$ nvidia-smi --query-gpu=name --format=csv,noheader
GeForce GT 650M
```

Answer (score 9):

You can run `nvidia-smi -L` to list all the NVIDIA GPUs in the system. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 with CUDA 11.3 .

Answer (score 5):

Most can be found out by using the lspci command in conjunction with grep.

Most GPU's are listed with model name with the following command:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the program **nvclock**. It offers a number of options, mainly for overclocking the card (memory and GPU) and temperature/fan control, but it also provides an information option which will give you the **exact architecture** of the chip you have:

`nvclock -i`

Answer (score 0):

**glxinfo**

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
glxinfo
```

contains:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Quadro M1200/PCIe/SSE2
```

Tested on Ubuntu 23.04.

**clinfo**

```
sudo apt-get install clinfo
clinfo
```

contains:

```
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Quadro M1200
```

This is the analogue of `glxinfo` but for OpenCL, my GPU setup is described at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542808/how-to-compile-opencl-on-ubuntu/33483311#33483311

**Settings -> About (tested Ubuntu 20.04, 23.04)**

You can either open settings by clicking on top right menu, or you can just do:

- Super key (AKA Windows key)
- Type "about" and select the entry

So under "Graphics" I can see that my GPU model is

> Quadro M1200/PCIe/SSE2

[image]

Some other things it can show:

- "Software Rendering" (Ubuntu 23.10): graphics card not working at all
- "NV117": I think this means it is using Nouveau

**nvidia-settings**

Mixes runtime with some static info.

[image]

More details: [How do I check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card/692412#692412)