# Set Ubuntu to use Nvdia VGA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

when I checked which graphic driver my laptop uses. it is using both my nvidia and intel graphic driver.

based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/503438/340873) post, he said that

> [VGA controller] at the end of each device. Whatever device has it, is the active GPU

but in my case it uses both.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor     Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] [10de:0de3] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I wanted it to use my nvidia for default and intel as my fallback.

will I have issues here if I am using both?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run 2 different drivers at the same time, which is what your system is trying to do. If you have not installed a dedicated graphics card from NVIDIA,you cannot use the NVIDIA driver!  The 2 drivers that you have installed will fight each other. In other words, you have to remove the NVIDIA driver completly using one of these commands in a terminal [sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current] or [sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current-updates] or [sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*] depending on what kind of machine you are using, laptop, desktop,ect., you can copy and paste these commands into a terminal, BUT do not copy the symbol [ or ] in the command line I only used them for seperation. After removing everything to do with NVIDIA, shut down and reboot system. when you restart, your system will be operating using only the INTEL driver:-) If you do have a dedicated NVIDIA graphics card installed, the above commands should still be used, so that you can do a fresh install of NVIDIA driver through (software & updates--additional drivers box) , the UBUNTU recomended driver is not always the driver that will work best, case in point, I am using UBUNTU 14.10 and UBUNTU 15.04 and the driver they recomend is version 340.46, but I have to use version 331.104 for everything to work correctly :-)  If at any time you change driver being used, you need to follow above commands and purge all remains of previous driver, and then install your new driver, once new driver is installed, shutdown and restart. Most but not all systems disables intel driver automaticly when a dedicated graphics card is installed so you might check your BIOS at startup and make sure it is disabled if you are running a dedicated NVIDIA graphics card.  Happy UBUNTUING:-)