# Two graphic cards - how to check which one is used, and how to ensure that the right one is used?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, radeon

I have a laptop - Clevo P150EM, with two graphic cards onboard. Intel HD Graphics 4000 and a Radeon HD 8970M.

I would like to check which one is used, and ensure that the Intel HD 4000 is used as a main card, and use the Radeon HD 8970M only for gaming. Any suggestions anyone? ;)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Have you looked at `xrandr` ? 'man xrandr' will provide the manual page for it. It looks like it's what you are looking for. Let us know.

Comment: Try this answer (Geo's answer): http://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card

Comment: @Muzaffar [Answers there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card) explain how to check what graphics card is being used--but dziki is also asking how to *ensure* a particular card gets used. Are you recommending the advice in [Anne van Rossum's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68028/how-do-i-check-if-ubuntu-is-using-my-nvidia-graphics-card#comment825901_503438)?

Comment: The one with [VGA controller] is the one being used. In my PC it worked, but I have only one card at it showed that it is being used.Maybe I misunderstood something. Feel free to correct me if so.