# Is there a 3dmark for ubuntu

Tags: benchmarks

I don't want this to test my gpu I would only like one to have on my big monitor playing and I don't know if I can get 3dmark for ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3dmark test DirectX performance. Ubuntu / Linux uses OpenGL. So simply: No there is no 3dmark for Ubuntu.

Maybe this helps you to test your system:

[Is there a benchmark tool for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198978/is-there-a-benchmark-tools-for-ubuntu)

**What I recommend you to test the systems 3D performance cross platform is the** `Unigine Heaven Benchmark`:

https://unigine.com/products/heaven/download/

This Benchmark is free and uses OpenGL and is available for Linux, Mac and Windows.

Comment: Although you only refer to the benchmarking aspect of Unigine, it can just as well be used to run the demo in a loop without benchmarking it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I see, was late yesterday when I gave my answer.. Should have slept!

Answer (score 2):

There is no current version of 3DMark for Linux, even though they DO have OpenGL benchmarks (Ice Storm (which has an Android version) and a downgraded version of Cloud Gate called Slingshot). Both are quite light and are not that great for testing PC gaming hardware (I get ~300 fps on a gaming notebook from 2011 when running Ice Storm on Windows).

They currently do not have any plans to create a linux version, but they are watching SteamOS carefully and may release Linux versions if SteamOS becomes very popular.

Like Flatron said, for now just use the Unigine Benchmarks like Heaven and Valley.

Source:
http://community.futuremark.com/forum/showthread.php?181979-3DMark-for-Linux (Source #4 is a futuremark employee)