# Install Prime95/Mprime on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation, cpu, stress-testing

How do we install Mprime or Prime95 on Ubuntu 20.04 using `apt`? Or must it be installed from a `.deb`/`tar.gz` file?

I am planning to stress test my Threadripper CPU using this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The software is available for download from the developers at [mersenne.org](https://www.mersenne.org/download/).

Download the Linux 64-bit version of the `tar.gz`, then extract the archive.

You can open the `readme.txt` file, which includes a section called "INSTRUCTIONS".

Feel free to read the entire file for more details on how to use the software, but here are the basics (info pertaining to Windows/MacOS is redacted):

> Create a directory to hold the executable and associated files.  Make sure you have
> write access to this new directory.
>
> Now run the program.  In Linux, cd to the directory and type "./mprime -m".
> You may need to install the included libraries.
>
> There are two ways to use this program.  The automatic way uses a central server,
> which we call the PrimeNet server, to get work to do and report your results.
> You do not need a permanent connection to the Internet.
>
> The second method is the manual method.  It requires a little more work
> and monitoring.  This is recommended for computers with no Internet access
> or with some kind of firewall problem that prevents the automatic method
> from working.

This being said, there are probably better ways to benchmark your CPU than Prime95.  See the topic: [CPU benchmarking utility for Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634513/cpu-benchmarking-utility-for-linux)

Comment: I use a great many CPU stressors/benchmark programs, including several I wrote myself. The prime95 torture test, maximum heat generation test is the best I have ever found for pure energy consumption. I use it for thermal management testing on my systems, and actually have never cared about the performance results.