# Kubuntu Limited CPU power?

Tags: kubuntu, cpu

CPU power on softwares on Ubuntu reach 100% , while in Kubuntu it fluctuates between 60-80%
What could be the cause ? Why Kubuntu 21 limits the CPU power?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I am also skeptical that your assumption is correct which would make your question impossible to answer. What exactly are you calling "CPU power"? How are you measuring this?  Are you running benchmarks or stress tests? What makes you believe your CPU is being limited in any way? In order to answer a question like this, we will need more thorough technical details.

Comment: CPU usage , by default a software i use on Kubuntu 21 it the usage across all cores is between 60-80 , while in Ubuntu 20 the cpu usage is at max 100% and also the software finish noticeably faster , I also tried to set the performance mode on Kubuntu it made it 90% CPU usage which it seems Kubuntu does have limitation on CPU somehow maybe due to some power saving feature I'm not aware about.

Comment: Have you tried to benchmark your CPU? https://askubuntu.com/questions/634513/cpu-benchmarking-utility-for-linux

Comment: I will try to Benchmark the two distros later , but I ran two softwares and they clearly don't use the full CPU power on Kubuntu.

Comment: Until you run benchmarking or stress testing software that deliberately runs the CPU at max you cannot make that claim.