# ATI Radeon Mobility X1600 drivers installation

Tags: 12.10, ati, graphics, radeon, macbook-pro

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my old Macbook Pro 2006. It has a ATI Radeon Mobility X1600 256MB and I would grateful if you could tell me how to install the graphic card drivers.
So far the Ubuntu runs fine.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the following command: [`lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system/254877#254877). Edit your question including that information.

Answer (score 2):

[The Unofficial AMD Linux Driver Wiki says](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide):

> ATI Radeon 9500-9800, Xpress200-1250, 690G, 740G, **X300-X2500**, Mobility RadeonHD 2300 If your card is on that list, **you are limited to open-source drivers** on Ubuntu Lucid/10.04 (and later). If you really need the proprietary Catalyst/fglrx driver, you will have to use an older Linux distribution, such as Debian Lenny/5.0.x or Ubuntu Hardy/8.04.x. NOTE: If you enter your card information on AMD/ATI's driver page, it will offer you the Catalyst 9-3 driver to download. However, the Catalyst 9-3 driver doesn't support X servers past 1.5, and it will not work with Precise (or anything later than Lucid/10,04)! !!!SO BE CAREFUL!!! If you tried to install Catalyst on a system with one of these cards, see the 'Removing the Driver' section to restore the default/pre-installed drivers.

This maybe include the *ATI Radeon Mobility X1600* graphic card. It means that your card isn't supported anymore by the proprietary [Fglrx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI) driver. But you card is supported by the open source [Radeon](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) driver:

> RV530/RV560                 Radeon X1600/X1650/X1700

so your card should work.

If the output from this command: [`lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system/254877#254877) is: `Kernel driver in use: radeon`, your Radeon graphic driver is loaded.

**See:**

- Which [features the Radeon driver provides for your card](http://wiki.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature). I think your card belongs to the R500 family.
- [How to perform a detailed and quick 3D performance test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31913/how-to-perform-a-detailed-and-quick-3d-performance-test)