# How can I check my nvidia opengl library is working or not from terminal in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I installed nvidia in ubuntu 16.04, currently the os uses GPU graphcis (which I checked in system settings>details)

However, I would like to confirm about nvidia opengl library  is working or not?
after run glxinfo | grep OpenGL
it gives:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation OpenGL renderer string: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 OpenGL core profile version string:
4.5.0 NVIDIA 418.39 OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA OpenGL core profile context flags: (none) OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile OpenGL core profile extensions: OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.39 OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA OpenGL context flags: (none) OpenGL profile mask: (none) OpenGL extensions: OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 418.39 OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20 OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Is it OK?
Is there any suggestion please?

Comment: Libraries are usually not something that works. Instead, they are used by other programs. What makes you think an opengl lib not ising working?

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks for your comment. Yes, I agree with you. 1. I want to check the library is installed successfully or not? 2.  So I need to use some example to run with nvidia opengl library

Comment: Run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

Comment: This is all very vague indeed. 1. Opengl is preinstalled, and you can run `dpkg -l | grep libgl` to verify. 2. Since you insist to run something, they benchmark tools https://askubuntu.com/questions/31913/how-to-perform-a-detailed-and-quick-3d-performance-test.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever. your answer was helpful